# How to write a Regular Expression to ignore a word in a sentence

Tags: regex

I would like to write a regular expression to ignore a single word or set of characters (any) in a sentence or phrase.

Example:

I would like to ignore the string "mytest-01"

```
snmp-server community mytest-01 RO
```

Comment: What language do you use, what have you tried? What is the result you hope?

Comment: Could you provide more example phrases and a more general description of what you want to ignore and what you want to capture?

Comment: did not work:    snmp-server community (?!^ABC$)(^.*$) RO 
did not work:   snmp-server community (?!^ABC$) RO
did not work:   snmp-server community (([a-z0-9]+){2}) RO
did not work:   snmp-server community ([a-z0-9]+) RO

Comment: Some of those regular expression try to match the _beginning_ and the _end_ of the string in the _middle_. Of course they will not work. Have you tried [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/)? You’ll save a lot of time with that…

Comment: examples:  ignore City-02 could be any thing in this position    :::::::::
 description Router for City-02 Mgt Port

Comment: example:  ignore Access-list-03 could be any string of characters numbers or specials ::::::
access-class Access-list-03 in

Comment: You can also edit your question to add substantial information such as this.

Comment: example:  ignore string (10.1.1.1) could be any ip address    :::::::::
snmp-server host 10.1.1.1 version 3 priv Solarwinds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `[\w+-]+\d+|(.+?)` (using discard technique)

see [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yI0oA1/3).

Comment: the string mytest-01 is a set of arbitrary characters.  I may not know what the string may be so I just need to ignore the entire string all together.  basically skipping the string.

Comment: sorry.. i dint get you.. are you trying to ignore keywords or strings of type `mytest-01` ie.. `\w+-\d+`??

Answer (score 0):

You can match the 2 parts before and after the string and then combine by replacing with `$1$2`:

```
(.*)\bmytest-01\b\s*(.*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zH2pP5/2).

Comment: This one worked when I modified it to the following::::::: (.*)\b.*\b\s*(.*)